# Why is log4net not writing to a file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, log4net

I have added all parts of log4net, however it doesn't write to the file.
I'm working with the VS2012 LoadTest project.

Neither the `System.Console.WriteLine` or `Debug.WriteLine()` work, when running the LoadTest project.

I've added the assembly info line:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "web.config", Watch = true)]   //For log4net 1.2.10.0
```

I've:
- added webconfig section
- initialized an configured an XML initializer
- initialized new log4net with the proper log

My app.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Settings_CacheExplosion.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>

</configuration>
```

My class:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WebAndLoadTestProject1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text;
    using log4net;
    using log4net.Core;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;


    public class Settings_CacheExplosion : WebTest
    {
        private static readonly ILog activityLog = LogManager.GetLogger("Activity"); 

        private static int _ctidsCounter { get; set; }

        public static int CtidsCounter
        {

            get
            {

                if (_ctidsCounter == 2000)
                {
                    _ctidsCounter = 1000;
                }
                return _ctidsCounter++;
            }
            set
            {
                _ctidsCounter = value;
            }
        }

        public Settings_CacheExplosion()
        {
            this.PreAuthenticate = true;

            CtidsCounter = 1000;

            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }


        public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
        {
            WebTestRequest request1 = new WebTestRequest("http://clientservice.mam.qasite-services.com/settings");

            request1.Method = "POST";

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ctid={0}", CtidsCounter));

            request1.QueryStringParameters.Add("ctid", CtidsCounter.ToString(), false, false);
            StringHttpBody request1Body = new StringHttpBody();
            request1Body.ContentType = "";
            request1Body.InsertByteOrderMark = false;
            request1Body.BodyString = "";
            request1.Body = request1Body;

            activityLog.Debug(string.Format("ctid={0}", CtidsCounter));
            //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ctid={0}", CtidsCounter));

            yield return request1;
            request1 = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your web.config log4net section and the code you use to initialize it

Comment: Worked for me last time I used it. Must be something you're doing wrong ;)

Comment: can you post the code of the web.config's log4net section?

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield worked even when running the loadtest itself and not just the webtest?

Comment: Have you manage to make this work for the webtest? @EladBenda

Comment: cannot remember :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your **app.config**:

`<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />`

This works to ensure that the app will refuse to start on .NET 4.0 with an error on startup.

If you are using Framework .NET4.5, log4net does not support it. See frameworks section in http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html

Comment: Create a new project using the NET4 framework. No other way if you want to use log4net that is.

Comment: staying at 4.5 what logging option do i have?

Comment: Did you change the setting in your app.config to be: `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />`, did you recreate your project?

Comment: changed in the project properties and it changed the app.config automatically to: `    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>`. I have rebuilt and the file isn't created

Comment: In your app.config, try changing your `<root></root>` to `<logger name="Activity">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>` If this does not work, try creating a brand new NET4 test project, following the same steps you undertook. I cannot refer you to other logging libraries, you can always go for custom logging, but that is almost always a hassle and you are losing quite a lot of functionality.

Comment: And last but not least, reading through the log4net [FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html), log4net cannot log to a FileAppender from a Web Application.

Answer (score 5):

If you want log4net to read from the app.config, you have to add this to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Comment: have similar one. didn't help

Comment: This was the missing part of the project that prevented me from creating/add to logs. Saved me a lot of time. Thanks @akatakritos

Answer (score 1):

use `<param name = "Activity" value="Settings_CacheExplosion.txt" />` instead of `<file value="Settings_CacheExplosion.txt" />`. in your xml configuration section.