# Why is log4net not recognized in configuration file?

Tags: c#, log4net

I wrote a test console application in C# using [log4net](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://logging.apache.org/log4net/&ei=BqETUuq9B8LXtQax9YGoCw&usg=AFQjCNEdDcVKM8X4j-ILZQt9pLW1G13vdA&sig2=6tt81XT5eOpSzI_an6FP3g&bvm=bv.50952593,d.Yms&cad=rja):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

namespace Log4Net_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            log.Info("Entering application");    
            log.Debug("Debug message");    
            log.Info("Leaving application");
        }
    }
}
```

My `App.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <log4net>
    <!-- A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender -->
    <appender name="A1" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="false" />

      <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-4timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="A1" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Executing the test program ends up in the following error message:

```
log4net:ERROR Exception while reading ConfigurationSettings. Check your .config
file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognize
d configuration section log4net.
```

What is wrong with my configuration file?

**UPDATE 1:**
The `configSections´ part was missing, as pointed out in the accepted answer. But I also had to remove the`startup`section, otherwise the same error appeared. I do not know why the`startup` section is causing the problem, too. Perhaps someone more experienced can tell and write a comment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to add `log4net` also in the section block

```
<configSections>

<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/> 

</configSections>
```

Comment: Thank you, this section was missing.

Answer (score 13):

The startup section needed to be removed as well because **log4net** does not support **Framework .NET4.5**

You can see my similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13236410/1783224

Or you can see the supported frameworks in the documentation: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html

Comment: I've got it working fine with 4.5 startup block, as long as the configSection with log4net comes before it.

Comment: I can confirm the fix @nathanchere suggested

Comment: This is incorrect. The Log4Net supports .NET 4.5 for sure.

Comment: Current version of log4net works correctly with .NET 4.5 using the solution above

Comment: Even above startup didn't solve my problem.  It had to be the first child of configuration. It appears to work fine with 4.5.

Answer (score 4):

You should also remember that section block <**configSections**> must be under the <**configuration**> otherwise will occurred an error:

> Exception while reading ConfigurationSettings. Check your .config file
>   is well formed XML.

For example:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>   
  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->   
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="service.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <!--
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      -->
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger.%method - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>   
  </log4net>   
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Wow - this helped me! But there is even more: The configSections-node HAS TO BE THE FIRST node under the configuration-node or else one will receive that message you mentioned.

Comment: this helped me also. config sections is the first node.

Comment: yaaa, this helped me too.

Comment: The comment made me think a bit - I have always had a separate file for the log4net.config - and seeing the startup at the bottom - made me move the log4net section into the app.config (I had already added a configuration section) and after moving the log4net section - it finally started working (.Net 4.6.1 project target) - not sure what changed - but now it is logging and not throwing exceptions on load.